# Taskbar shortcut icons keep disappearing after VS 11 Beta install

Tags: windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2012, taskbar

I recently installed VS 11 Beta and since then I experience something strange.
Several times during the week icons of some applications that I pinned on the task-bar just vanish.  Well, they not actually vanish, but they are replce with the same default windows icon.

I can resolve this with the following procedure:

1. Navigate to c:\Users\\AppDate\Local
2. Delete IconCache.db
3. Kill explorer.exe via the taskmanager.
4. Restart explorer.exe via the taskmanager.

This helps for some time, but then the icons just are being replaced again. The last time it happened was after a security update for Visual Studio 2005/2008 SP1 was installed.

Anyone experienced the same problem?
Does somebody have a clue why this is happening and how to resolve this, other than uninstalling VS 11 completely?

Comment: FYI, the product does not have an official name yet. When it does, it will not be "Visual Studio 2011" (a past year). The "11" in "Visual Studio 11" refers to the version number (Visual Studio 2010 was version 10; VS2008 was version 9).

Answer (score 1):

The problem I described finally disappeared after installing the RTM version of Visual Studio 2012. However, during the period in-between, I used a batch-file of Shawn Brink to restore the icons:

```
:: Created by: Shawn Brink
:: http://www.sevenforums.com
:: Tutorial:  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html


@echo off
cls
echo The Explorer process must be killed to delete the Icon DB.
echo.
echo Please SAVE ALL OPEN WORK before continuing.
echo.
pause
echo.
C:\Windows\System32\taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
echo.
echo Attempting to delete Icon DB...
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
del IconCache.db /f /q /ah
echo.
pause
echo Icon DB has been successfully deleted.
echo.

:main
echo Windows 7 must be restarted to rebuild the Icon DB.
echo.

:wrong
set /p choice=Restart now? (Y/N) and press Enter:
If %choice% == y goto Yes
If %choice% == Y goto Yes
If %choice% == n goto No
If %choice% == N goto No
goto wrong

:Yes
C:\Windows\System32\shutdown /R /f /t 00
exit


:No
echo.
echo Restart aborted. Please remember to restart the computer later.
echo.
echo You can now close this command prompt window.
explorer.exe
```